# Are there some tools to delete redundant resource in MFC project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

Sometimes, I add some resource(png, string, bmp) to use. But because of some reasons, these resources may get redundant. The project is so large, many people join the development. So, there are lots of redundant resources.

Now, we need to translate the language in resource into other languages. So, we have to delete all redundant resource to increase the efficency.

Besides, have to remove all unnecessary png, bmp and other resources to make the final setup.exe smaller.

**Resource Symbol Editor of Visual Studio is hard to use, I can delete an item one time. I need to find another tool.**

I'm wondering if there are some existing tools to help me to that.
Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .RC file is just a text file. Download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and edit the resources directly in there. It's much faster and you can do global search and replaces.